# wp_nav_menu custom walker <a> class

Tags: theme-development, menus

So I'm learning about custom walkers and I've run into a few issues. I've got a custom walker set up. One issue I'm having is figuring out how to add a class to the `<a>` inside of the start_el function. The relevant code looks like:

```
/**
     * Filter the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's anchor element.
     *
     * @since 3.6.0
     * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
     *
     * @param array $atts {
     *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<a>` element, empty strings are ignored.
     *
     *     @type string $title  Title attribute.
     *     @type string $target Target attribute.
     *     @type string $rel    The rel attribute.
     *     @type string $href   The href attribute.
     * }
     * @param object $item  The current menu item.
     * @param array  $args  An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
     * @param int    $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     */
    $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

    $attributes = '';
    foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
        if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
            $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
            $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
        }
    }

    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
    $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

    /**
     * Filter a menu item's title.
     *
     * @since 4.4.0
     *
     * @param string $title The menu item's title.
     * @param object $item  The current menu item.
     * @param array  $args  An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
     * @param int    $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     */
    $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;
```

I've got a feeling that the way to do this is through passing the new class with $item_output, but I haven't been able to find how to do this (what the code would look like).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to alter the `$attributes` string, since that outputs the attributes in the `a` tag. The following is untested:

```
$myClass = 'some-custom-class';
$myClassAdded = false;
$attributes = '';
foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
    if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
        $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
        if( $attr == 'class' ){
            $value .= ' ' . $myClass;
            $myClassAdded = true;
        }
        $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
    }
}
if( !$myClassAdded ){
     $attributes .= ' class="' . $myClass . '"';
}
```

I also added an extra boolean in case the class attribute is never found in the loop.